# There exists a one-to-one function $g$ such that $f\circ g$ is constant

Tags: real-analysis, implicit-function-theorem

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^1$ function. Then there exists a continuous one-to-one function $g$ on $[0,1]$ such that $f\circ g=$constsnt.

Attempt: If $f\equiv 0$ then nothing to prove. So assume that $f\neq 0$. That is there is some $(x_0,y_0)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $f(x_0,y_0)\neq 0.$ Now we can apply [Implicit function theorem](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/320753684_Inverse_Function_Theorem_and_its_Applications#pf6)  to say that there is a function $\phi: U_{x_0}\to V_{y_0}$ such  that $f(x,\phi(x))=0.$

Now how to get a function from $[0,1]$? This is not clear to me.

Comment: What is the domain of $g$?

Comment: I think the answer to your question is Step 5 of the accepted answer in the duplicate cited by @Javi.

Comment: @RobertShore, yeah but that is from $(0,1)$ not from $[0,1].$ Can it be extended to $[0,1]$?